# How to calculate sums for each row in two-dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array, with random numbers:

```java
        int[][] doubleArr = new int[2][3];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < doubleArr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < doubleArr[i].length; j++) {
                doubleArr[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(-10, 10);
                System.out.print(doubleArr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

In the snippet below I was able to compute the total sum of all positive integers from all elements of two-dimensional array:

```java
       int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < doubleArr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < doubleArr[i].length; j++) {
                if(doubleArr[i][j] > 0){
                    sum += doubleArr[i][j];

                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
```

How can I calculate and store the sums for each row of two-dimensional array separately?

Comment: What string are you referring to? If your random numbers were [1,2,3][4,5,6], what is your expectation in terms of what this 'string sum' should be?

Comment: Calling a two-dimensional array of `int` a "double array" or `doubleArr` is a bit confusing since there is a type `double` and most people would think "double array" meant `double[]`.

Comment: By "string sum" do you mean "row sum," the sum of each row of the two-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

You can store "sum" in array or arraylist after your inner for loop gets executed each time.

```
int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < doubleArr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < doubleArr[i].length; j++) {
            if(doubleArr[i][j] > 0){
                sum += doubleArr[i][j];

            }

        }
        //Store your sum here in array, arraylist etc.

    }
System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
    int[][] doubleArr = new int[2][3];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < doubleArr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < doubleArr[i].length; j++) {
            doubleArr[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(20) - 10;
            System.out.print(doubleArr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    int sum = 0;
    int[] sums = new int[2];
    int[] sumCols = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < doubleArr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < doubleArr[i].length; j++) {
            if(doubleArr[i][j] > 0){
                sum += doubleArr[i][j];
                sums[i] += doubleArr[i][j];
                sumCols[j] += doubleArr[i][j];
            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    System.out.println("sums = " + Arrays.toString(sums));
    System.out.println("sumCols = " + Arrays.toString(sumCols));
```

Which gives for example:

```
-5 -7 3 
7 -10 7 
sum = 17
sums = [3, 14]
sumCols = [7, 0, 10]
```